# Difference between the date returned by hadoop fs -ls and hadoop fs -stat

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Is there any difference between the dates returned by

```
hadoop fs -ls myfile
```

and

```
hadoop fs -stat myfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although by default both will display modification time, `-stat` shows time in UTC while `-ls` converts it to local timezone and drops seconds. From Hadoop [file system shell doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat):

> **stat** 
> Usage: hadoop fs -stat [format] path 
> ...
> %x and %y show UTC date as “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss”